# error while installing hadoop windows 7 32bit

Tags: windows, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I want to install hadoop in windows so I come up with this tutorial 
I follow step by step

http://toodey.com/2015/08/10/hadoop-installation-on-windows-without-cygwin-in-10-mints/#comment-4502

but after I use this command

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

this error display

I have no idea how to solve it

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdTub.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any blank lines or spaces before the first line`<?xml version="1.0"?>`?

Comment: Yes, I had a space before <?xml   > and I have removed it .. but I got another type of error. please see the updated image

Comment: Sorry, Unable to view the image clearly!

Comment: I tried the command and got another error, please see the updated image in the post

Comment: That screenshot is almost impossible to read... I see `Syntax error in URI` and `illegal <something>` in the `bin/data/namenode`. So, I think one of the path variables that you set is wrong.

Comment: double thanks .. I fixed the URI , but still have something wrong.. please check the updated image

Comment: I change the image so it can be more clear

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file `hdfs-site.xml`, remove the Drive letter from the path values.

For example, If the properties are defined as

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>C:/hadoop_home/name</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>C:/hadoop_home/data</value>
</property>
```

modify them to,

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/hadoop_home/name</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/hadoop_home/data</value>
</property>
```

Then format the namenode `hdfs namenode -format`.

Comment: hopefully we are almost done, just very few things to be checked. when typingthe jps command , it shows that only two services are running, those are jps and resourcemanager. also, I could see that namenode directory has been created , but no datanode directory has been created.